# How to graphically show a quantity in Android?

Tags: android, graphics, colorbox, draw

I am working on a app where I want to show a quantity in a rectangle. The following is what I need. I have 2 values, say totalMoney and spentMoney.
I want to show the remaining money (i.e. totalMoney - spentMoney) in a rectangle box in 2 colors.

Like this:

```
|======================| 
|///////////|          |
|////50%////|          |   
|///////////|          |
|======================|
```

This rectangle will be in a custom View, in collaboration with other components like textview etc.

How do I get this in Android? I am working on Android 2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html).

Here is an example of a custom one.

```
    <ProgressBar style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="7dip"
  android:id="@+id/pop1000Bar"
  android:max="1000"
  android:progress="500"
  android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbarlayers"
  >
  </ProgressBar>
```

progressbarlayers is an xml file that defines how I want the progress bar to look. Here is how mine is set up.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="5dip" />
        <gradient
                android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d"
                android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="#ff747674"
                android:angle="270"
        />
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:id="@android:id/progress"
>
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners
                android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#A9F505"
                android:endColor="#FFF700"
                android:angle="270" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
        <size android:height="3dip"/>



            <gradient
                    android:startColor="#80ffd300"
                    android:centerColor="#80ffb600"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#a0ffcb00"
                    android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
<item
    android:id="@android:id/progress"
>
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners
                android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#A9F505"
                android:endColor="#FFF700"
                android:angle="270" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

It comes out looking like this:

[image]

But you can make it look like whatever you need it to.

**EDIT:** There are many ways you could achieve getting text on to them. If your parent layout is a RelativeLayout you can just stack a TextView on top of the progress bar and call setText on the text view each time the progress is updated. Probably what is a better approach is subclass ProgressBar to draw it on there for you. [Here is an example of that](http://colintmiller.com/2010/10/how-to-add-text-over-a-progress-bar-on-android/). They just made a new View that extends ProgressBar, and override the onDraw to draw some text to the canvas each time as well as painting the bars and background.

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer... I will give it a try now.... and what about the text on top of that ... how can I have that... as that is also required

Comment: thank yo very much... I am giving it a try... and I know it will work.. So hats off to you...

Comment: one small query... in my requirement I dont want a changing/growing progresss bar.. I just want to set a value and thats it... will your solution still work

Answer (score 0):

The most flexible way would be to do a CustomView.

Use ImageView as a base class and override **onDraw**

onDraw gives you a Canvas and you could draw what you like.